# use QDesktopServices.openUrl() to open window created by QWebEnginePage::createWindow()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

when a JavaScript program requests to open a document in a new window, `QWebEnginePage::createWindow()` would be called to create a new window, while I want to **(1)** open the new window using `QDesktopServices.openUrl(url)` instead, and **(2)** keep the view in my QWebEngineView unchanged. My solution cannot satisfy (2), so any simpler solutions ?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore import *
import sys,os


class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage): 
  def __init__(self, parent, mdicts=[]):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.backwardUrl=''

  def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, navigationType, isMainFrame):  # Navigation requests can be delegated to the Qt application instead of having the HTML handler engine process them by overloading this function. This is necessary when an HTML document is used as part of the user interface, and not to display external data, for example, when displaying a list of results.# The QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor class offers further options for intercepting and manipulating requests.
    # print('acceptNavigationRequest-----------------', navigationType, isMainFrame)
    if self.backwardUrl and isMainFrame:
      print('blocked------------',self.backwardUrl)
      self.setUrl(self.backwardUrl)
      QDesktopServices.openUrl(self.backwardUrl)
      self.backwardUrl=''   
      return False 
    return True

  def createWindow(self, windowType):
    print('createWindow')
    self.backwardUrl=self.url()
    return self
    
class WebEngineView(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # self.mousePressEvent=lambda event:print('mousePressEvent',event.pos())
        # self.mouseMoveEvent=lambda event:print('mouseMoveEvent',event.pos())

        self.webPage = WebEnginePage(self)#self.page()  # QWebEnginePage()

        self.setPage(self.webPage)
        # self.setUrl(QUrl('https://dict.eudic.net/liju/en/good#TingLiju'))

        self.webPage.setUrl(QUrl('https://dict.eudic.net/liju/en/good#TingLiju'))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    webEngineView = WebEngineView()
    webEngineView.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a page that only serves to obtain the url, and when you get it, delete it and launch the url with `QDesktopServices::openUrl()`:

```py
class FakePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.urlChanged.connect(self.handle_url_changed)

    @pyqtSlot(QUrl)
    def handle_url_changed(self, url):
        QDesktopServices.openUrl(url)
        self.deleteLater()


class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def createWindow(self, windowType):
        return FakePage(self)


class WebEngineView(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.webPage = WebEnginePage(self)
        self.setPage(self.webPage)
        self.webPage.setUrl(QUrl("https://dict.eudic.net/liju/en/good#TingLiju"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much ! I think the implementation of ```handle_url_changed``` could be simplified to   ```QDesktopServices.openUrl(url); self.deleteLater()```